# Should I verify that the output directory exists or just create it?

Tags: usability, directory

In my job, I create apps where I'm converting data and frequently need, among other things, an input and an output directory.  Obviously, the input directory needs to exist, but for the output directory, should I verify it exists and prompt the user if it doesn't, or try to create it if it doesn't and prompt only if that fails.

For example, if the user inputs c:\output\run1 and there is a c:\output directory but no run1 directory, should I just create that directory and proceed, or should I force the user to enter a directory that actually exists?

Comment: Use a folder selection dialog that also allows for new folder creation. Offer manual input as an alternative. Draw attention to the fact that the specified folder does not exist by whatever non-modal notification means you prefer and offer a checkbox to create it on continuation.

Answer (score 10):

There is a good chance that someone will want to output content to a directory that exists, but **make a typo when entering it**.  If you don't prompt the user and just create it, they are likely to get frustrated because you aren't saving it into the directory that they *think* they saved it to.

If on the other hand you let them know that the directory doesn't exist, if they made a typo, and they know that it should exist, they are more likely to double check the directory.

So I would **prompt them** if the directory doesn't exist and ask whether they want the app to automatically create it, or choose a different directory.

Comment: +1 Standard pattern in desktop development is to show a dialog allowing the user to select the folder from the OS's folder tree. The dialog can optionally be configured to allow creation of a new folder. End result: folder should exist after dialog is exited. If it turns out it no longer is when you come to save files in that folder that is an error condition of which the user should be notified as it sh/could only happen by somebody deleting an existing (however briefly) folder in the meantime.

Comment: Perfect response - I also think it is key to include a "Would you like to create?" dialog after.

Answer (score 2):

for the good reasons mentioned above, if the directory was manually typed, but it doesn't exists, the UI should notify the user.

However, I find prompts very intrusive (and archaic). I would suggest **in-line validation**. 
When the user finishes typing, and the focus leaves the textbox, you can asynchronously check to for the existence of the directory (or even general validity). If there is a problem, show it next or around the field, to notify about it. But don't bring the user's flow to a complete halt just for the chance there's a mistake.

You can read about the design pattern of in-line validation here:

- http://alistapart.com/article/inline-validation-in-web-forms
- http://quince.infragistics.com/Patterns/Inline%20Validation.aspx

Just as other input fields, like username or password, were once validated with pop-up dialog, it is time that this input field would also behave in a more modern and subtle manner.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In many scenarios, the act of creation of a directory is defaulted when there is no current directory. You can look at several Shell/DOS commands like '*touch*' which checks for a directory and creates one in case there isn't one.

However, speaking **in UX terms, this is bad**, by the fact that the **user is unaware of the decisions being made**. The core principle of UX is enabling the users and making them feel in control. By that virtue, you should always have a confirmation dialog to get the users permission "There is no *run1* directory inside *output* directory. Should I go ahead and create one?" You can then ask if the user wants to go ahead with the decision or makes some changes.

Comment: I don't think that users being unaware of decisions being made is _necessarily_ bad. Too often, software doesn't make _enough_ assumptions about a user's intentions.

Comment: Users do not need to know about the inner workings of the software necessarily. But, the output, specially if it is something like creation of a directory, should be run by the user.

Comment: Users don't care about 99% of the decisions that are happening. If this were a real pattern we couldn't use Windows without confirming the hundreds of decisions being made constantly by the OS about files, settings, etc. Design is all about abstraction

Comment: @JustinMeiners I just mentioned that the user don't care about inner workings BUT anything that impacts their workspace, they ought to be involved. Now, I do not know where you get your 99% figure, but, I would surely not go so far as to call hiding 99% decisions as an 'abstraction'.

Comment: @rk Your computer is constantly moving files, running programs, downloading, uploading, etc (99% made up number). All of these things are real operations that could potentially affect what a user is doing right now. the abstraction is then about determining what decisions a user most likely cares about right now etc. I get what your saying though - you shouldn't silently make a decision that dramatically affects a user.

Comment: @JustinMeiners I would like to know what applications I am running, what I am downloading, uploading, etc. We tend to dislike programs running in the background, doing what they like. Anyways, since you understand what I mean by 'decisions' the user needs to be aware of, I think there is no further need to discuss here.

Comment: @rk wow you seem to have taken my comments as some form of attack. I am sorry. (Also open task Manager and look at processes)

Comment: @JustinMeiners Umm, no I haven't. We aren't supposed to use this space as chat, that is it. And I always have my task manager open ;)